# Unit testing a function with user input() and print() in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

```
def welcome():
    for i in range(2): # my actual program has range(100)
        name = input("enter your name")
        print( "welcome "+name)
```

Let us assume we want to test the function welcome, with the user entering: "Alice" and "Bob" as input. I know how to test via unittest.mock if a funcion only contains input() or print() not both. Now my challenage is how to do unit test. My partial solution is as follows.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from unittest import TestCase
#import welcome as module_under_test
import welcome

class welcomeTests(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('welcome.input', create=True)
    @mock.patch('builtins.print', create=True)
    def testdictCreateSimple(self, mocked_input,mock_print):
        # The actual test
        mocked_input.side_effect = ["Alice","Bob"]
        welcome.welcome()
##      mock_print.assert_called_with("welcome Alice")
##      mock_print.assert_called_with("welcome Bob")
        # Showing what is in mock
        import sys
        sys.stdout.write(str( mock_print.call_args ) + '\n')
        sys.stdout.write(str( mock_print.call_args_list ) + '\n')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This seems very complecated. If someone could help also with pytest would be great.

Any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: Tests are not supposed to print.  They're supposed to assert.

Comment: I guess I know how to do this. I will post my solution to this.